# Value of type 'GIDSignIn' has no member 'hasAuthInKeychain'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Any workarounds to check if GIDSignIn has successfully authenticated (Google Sign-In for iOS) in view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards to `Google Sign-In for iOS` the `hasAuthInKeychain` has been replaced to `hasPreviousSignIn` in v5.0.0 release.

So basically you need to use `hasPreviousSignIn` for checking successfully authenticate.

Link to release notes:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release